# What is Firebase Analytics log events (not set) keyword recently i am facing

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using firebase analytics on my android app.

There are some (not set) keywords on my dashboard.

What does (not set) mean?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAa3m.png)

Answer (score 0):

That means exactly what it says: this dimension hasn't been set for a certain number of hits.

Also, don't use Firebase for browsing the firebase data. Firebase's interface is pretty bad for anything more than debugging. Connect your Firebase to GA4 and use the Explore view there. It will allow you to mix in some more dimensions and metrics into your dashboards.

Comment: Could you please help me with converting my Firebase data to Google Analytics 4? I'm looking for guidance and assistance in this process.

Comment: Oh most definitely. Here you go: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en

Comment: I've already connect firebase to GA4 for one our android gaming app, but still it's the same. Is there any possibility that you could help us fix this by connecting with any remote accessing tool, I'll be really happy if it gets fixed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you connected Firebase to GA4, then just look at the data in the GA4 Explore interface.